# How can I check how often all list elements from a list B occur in a list A?

Tags: python, performance

I have a python list A and a python list B with words as list elements. I need to check how often the list elements from list B are contained in list A. Is there a python method or how can I implement this efficient?

The python intersection method only tells me that a list element from list B occurs in list A, but not how often.

Comment: Use `collections.Counter`

Comment: you can try making a dictionary that keeps record of which element from list B occours in list A and how many times it occours

Answer (score 2):

```
import collections
counter_A = collections.Counter(A)
for word in B:
    print(word, '->', counter_A[word])
```

Comment: For completeness: `import collections`. Note you can just use `counter_A[word]` here, since `0` count is the default for inputs that aren't a key.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert list B to a set, so that checking if the element is in B is faster.

Then create a dictionary to count the amount of times that the element is in A if the element is also in the set of B

As mentioned in the comments `collections.Counter` does the "heavy lifting" for you

Answer (score 0):

> The python intersection method only tells me that a list element from
>   list B occurs in list A, but not how often.

Correct, but you can build on this principle. Iterate over the intersection using a dictionary comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

A = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
B = [2, 3, 5, 6]

c = Counter(A)

res = {k: c[k] for k in c.keys() & B}
# {2: 3, 3: 2, 5: 1}
```

A view of dictionary keys, i.e. `dict.keys` isn't strictly a `set`, but it has [`set`-like properties](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) such as `&` (intersection):

> Keys views are set-like since their entries are unique and hashable.